# скрипт работает в не по очереди

Tags: php

есть скрипт он выполняет одно условие раньше другого , суть такая выбираю чекбоксы и изменяю значения или удаляю вот html форма. Пролема в том что исполняется только удаление

```html
<form action="remove.php" name="multiform" id="multiform" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input chk-all" value="0" name="g1[]">
  <span class="custom-control-indicator"></span>
  <span class="custom-control-description">выделить все</span>
</label>
| <button type="submit" name="del">Удалить выделенные</button> |
| <button type="submit" name="publication">Опуликовать</button> |
| <button type="submit" name="shootPublcation">Снять пуликовать</button> |
<br>
<hr>
<div id="bg-danger"></div>
<?php
 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bd.php');

$result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT id, email, fullName, number_Phone, imgRealtorSmall, fileNameSmall FROM realtor ORDER BY id DESC');
$result->execute();
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $file = explode(',', $myrow['fileNameSmall']);
          foreach ($file as $key) {
     
        echo "
<label class='custom-control custom-checkbox'>
  <input type='checkbox' class='custom-control-input' name='g1[]' value='".$myrow['id']."'>
  <span class='custom-control-indicator'></span>
</label>
              <div class='row formBorder'>

                    <div class='col-md-3'>
                             <img src='../".$myrow['imgRealtorSmall'].$key."' style='background-size: cover; width: 130px; height: auto;'> 
                               
                    </div>
                      <div class='col-md-7 fullContactCompany'>ФИО: ".$myrow['fullName']."</div>
                  

                      <div class='col-md-7  fullContactCompany'>Емайл: ".$myrow['email']."</div>

                     <div class='col-md-7 fullContactCompany'>Телефоны: ".$myrow['number_Phone']."</div><div class='col-md-2'><a href='https://rl76.online/crm/employees/cabinet.php?val=".$myrow['id']."'  class='btn btn-primary'>Подронее</a></div>
                     
                    </div>";

     }
  }
 }     

?>
</form>
```

и сам php обработчик

```html
<?php

$comma_separated = implode(",", $_POST['g1']);
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/bd.php');

if(!isset($_POST["publication"]))
{
 $publication = "Опубликованно";
$sql = ('UPDATE realtor SET publication=:publication WHERE id IN (' . $comma_separated . ')');  
$sql = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sql->bindParam(':publication', $publication, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$sql->execute();
}


if(!isset($_POST["del"]))
{
 
 $oneArray = array_shift($_POST['g1']);
 unset($oneArray);

$result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT img_Realtor, filename FROM realtor WHERE id IN (' . $comma_separated . ')');
$result->execute(array(':id' => $_POST['g1']));
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

     unlink("../".$myrow['img_Realtor'].$myrow['filename']);
     
    }
  }
$sql = $pdo->prepare ('DELETE FROM realtor WHERE id IN (' . $comma_separated . ')');   
$sql->execute();
if ($sql) {
 $ddd[] = "Риелтор удалён";
 echo json_encode($ddd);
  }
}
```

Comment: Советовал бы использовать, единую точку входа и роутинг запросов, а так-же для избежания ложных срабатываний, не рекомендую держать файлы с открытыми запросами, к которым можно обращаться на прямую - без какого либо условия работы, задуманного алгоритма.

Comment: а ошибки какие нибудь есть? пробовал убрать кнопку удаления с формы вообще, какое тогда будет поведение?(я подозреваю что с формы отправляются все элементы). и убери из условий "!", иначе получится что когда придёт запрос на действие именно его ты и не выполнишь. и ещё, я бы на твоём месте посмотрел в сторону аяксов.

Comment: 1. зачем вам DISTINCT? 2. Зачем вы выполняете запрос с биндингом параметра :id если в припарке у вас этого параметра нет?